# Sum of Odds in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have some code written in OCaml

```
let rec sumodds n =
   if (n mod 2)<>0 then
   let sum = sumodds (n-1) in 
   n + sum
   else sumodds(n-1);;
```

and I am trying to add up all odd numbers from 0 to n, but I am not sure how to make the program stop once n reaches zero. If I could get some help that would be awesome. If there are any other mistakes in the program, feel free to let me know what they are.

Answer (score 0):

The way to get the function to stop is to test for the "stop condition". I.e., you need to add an `if` statement that tests whether you have reached such a low value for n that the result is obvious.

Very commonly a recursive function looks like this:

```
let rec myfun arg =
    if is_trivial_value arg then
        obvious_answer
    else
       let s = myfun (smallish_part_of arg) in
       combine arg s
```

You just need to add a test for the trivial value of your argument `n`.

**Update**

As @Goswin_von_Brederlow points out, another very common pattern for recursive functions is this:

```
let rec myfun2 accum arg =
    if is_trivial_vaue arg then
        accum
    else
        myfun2 (combine arg accum) (smallish_part_of arg)
```

This is the tail recursive transformation of the above form. You can code in either form, but they are different. So you need to keep them straight in your mind. As an FP programmer you need to (and will pretty easily) learn to translate between the two forms.

Comment: My problem is that if n reaches zero, I need to return "sum" but if i add a stop condition before I mention sum then there will be an error. how do i go about fixing this?

Comment: When the function is called with n = 0, the answer is obvious. You should just return the obvious answer. The outermost expression of your function will be an if statement. There's no need to calculate `sum` at that point. Look at `myfun` above.

Comment: @choochy That is not how you wrote the code. Your code recurses until it hits the (missing) stop condition n=0 and then when it returns from the recursion as you unravel it you add in all the n's you went through on the way down. So for n=0 you don't return the final sum but just the sum of all odd numbers from 0 to 0, i.e. 0. Then n=1 returns, then n=2, then n=3, then n=4, up until the outer most function returns the final result.

Comment: Note: The style where the stop condition returns the final result is what you get when you transform your code to be tail recursive.

Answer (score 0):

just add "if n <= 0 then n" in the 2nd line

Answer (score 0):

A way of looking at this is to break the problem down:

**Step 1:** You need to iterate over all of the numbers between `0` and `n`. We could generate a list.

```
# let sum_odds n =
    let lst = List.init (n+1) (fun x -> x) in
    lst;;
val sum_odds : int -> int list = <fun>
# sum_odds 14;;
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10; 11; 12; 13; 14]
```

**Step 2:** Now, you need to filter out the elements that are odd.

```
# let sum_odds n =
    let lst = List.init (n+1) (fun x -> x) in
    let is_odd x = x mod 2 = 1 in
  List.filter is_odd lst;;
val sum_odds : int -> int list = <fun>
# sum_odds 14;;
- : int list = [1; 3; 5; 7; 9; 11; 13]
```

**Step 3:** And then you need to sum those.

```
# let sum_odds n =
    let lst = List.init (n+1) (fun x -> x) in
    let is_odd x = x mod 2 = 1 in
    let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0 in
    lst |> List.filter is_odd |> sum;;
val sum_odds : int -> int = <fun>
# sum_odds 14;;
- : int = 49
```

Each of these problems is simpler than the sum of them, but having solved each individual step, the total problem is readily solved.

Of course, if you want to do it in one pass, there's no need to generate a list at all, nor iterate over it multiple times. We can just create a [sequence](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html).

```
# let sum_odds n =
    let is_odd x = x mod 2 = 1 in
    let sum = Seq.fold_left (+) 0 in
    Seq.ints 0
    |> Seq.take_while @@ (>=) n
    |> Seq.filter is_odd
    |> sum;;
val sum_odds : 'a -> int = <fun>
# sum_odds 14;;
- : int = 49
```